# How to request mobile version by using file_get_contents() in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, user-agent

Thanks for looking at my question.

I want to get the mobile version by the use of either file_get_contents() or cURL. I know that it can be done by the help of modifying the HTTP headers in the request. Can you please give me a simple example to do so?

Thanks again!

Regards,
Sanket

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As an alternative, [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [stream_context_create](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) can also be used:

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'header'  => 'User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/3B48b Safari/419.3',
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: I am either getting a message saying "This page has been moved here" or the desktop version of the site. Please help! Its not working. :(

Answer (score 9):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3" http://example.com/your-url
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the user agent string:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/3B48b Safari/419.3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Of course, if the site just redirects you to a mobile version (usually something like `m.example.com`), you could simply request that url instead with the headers unchanged.